# what is the difference between the following code segments?

Tags: java, image, javafx

One of these code segments works and the other doesn't but I can not figure out why. I have tried debugging the one that doesn't work. The meat of the code is literally the same, I copy-pasted it. The one that works was taken from a slightly larger program that originally displays two stages. The professor wants us to expand upon a part of the original program so I thought it would be best to make a new project to make it easier to read and upload. The problem is that the new one doesn't work.

```
        This One Works

   ***int num1 = (int) (Math.random()*61);
   int num2 = (int) (Math.random()*61);
   int num3 = (int) (Math.random()*61);

   Stage Tiles = new Stage();
   Tiles.setTitle("Tiles");
   FlowPane tilePane = new FlowPane();
   System.out.println(num1 +" " + num2 + " " + num3);

   ImageView image1 = new ImageView(String.valueOf(num1)+".png");
   ImageView image2 = new ImageView(String.valueOf(num2)+".png");
   ImageView image3 = new ImageView(String.valueOf(num3)+".png");

   tilePane.getChildren().addAll(image1,image2,image3);
   Scene secondScene = new Scene(tilePane);
   Tiles.setScene(secondScene);
   Tiles.show();
```

}***

```
           This One Does Not Work

public class Case_lab6a extends Application
```

{
    @Override

```
public void start(Stage main)
{
   int num1 = (int) (Math.random()*61);
   int num2 = (int) (Math.random()*61);
   int num3 = (int) (Math.random()*61);


   main.setTitle("Tiles v2");
   FlowPane tilePane = new FlowPane();
   System.out.println(num1 +" " + num2 + " " + num3);

   ImageView image1 = new ImageView(String.valueOf(num1)+".png");
   ImageView image2 = new ImageView(String.valueOf(num2)+".png");
   ImageView image3 = new ImageView(String.valueOf(num3)+".png");



   tilePane.getChildren().addAll(image1,image2,image3);
   Scene secondScene = new Scene(tilePane);
   main.setScene(secondScene);
   main.show();
}
```

Based On the Error I get The issue is related to the compiler not recognizing the image. I know the way I have it structured is weird and there is probably a better way to do it, but I have 61 images all stored in the src file.

EDIT:
Imports for the nonfunctional segment:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

imports for the working segment:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import static javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition.CENTER;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
```

output for the nonfunctional program:

```
23 35 22
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1118)
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:620)
    at javafx.scene.image.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:166)
    at lab6a.Case_lab6a.start(Case_lab6a.java:35)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found
    at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateUrl(Image.java:1110)
    ... 12 more
Exception running application lab6a.Case_lab6a
C:\Users\Kindness\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Comment: Maybe you should include the error message.

Comment: Add the full code *with* the `import` statements. Most likely an incorrect `import`.

Comment: JavaFX cannot find the image with that path. Either one of the images is missing resulting in an error that occurs randomly or you did use a different run configuration resulting in the images not being available via that path.

Comment: The error occurs every time I run the program, and the last three runs I have gone through and verified that the t files are in the correct place. I did not use a different configuration intentionally. I literally copy-pasted the code from my original program to the new one and the images are in the scr files in both programs.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] of the non-working code, along with your project structure? You mention you're sure the images are in the right place, but are they copied to the build output location when you build your project? If not, make sure your images (which are resources) are contained within a directory (directly or indirectly) marked as a "resources root" by your IDE. If you're using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle then all resources should be under `src/main/resources`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two code samples you posted, other than one of them directly instantiates a `Stage`:

```
Stage Tiles = new Stage();
```

While the other one (the one that you say does not work) expects you to pass in a `Stage` object when you call the `start()` method.

[Aside: The `Tiles` variable should be `tiles` to follow Java naming conventions. Class names start with capitals, variables should be camelCase.]

You said that the error is to do with images. It would be helpful for you to include the exact error message (and the full stack trace, if possible).

One thing that you should be aware of is that when you use `Math.random()` it could return `0`. Are your images numbered from 0 to 60? If not, perhaps it will fail to find the image file every now and then (at random).

By the way, to generate random ints you would do better to use:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int num1 = rand.nextInt(61);
int num2 = rand.nextInt(61);
int num3 = rand.nextInt(61);
```

Also, you can simplify `String.valueOf(num1)+".png"` to `num1 + ".png"`. Integers are automatically converted to strings when appended to a string. You've done that in the `System.out.println(num1 + " " + num2 + " " + num3)` line.

Comment: I am aware that it can currently generate a zero, that is my next problem to tackle.   When I was doing the initial assignment I could not get the program to work unless I used the `String.valueOf();` method.   I updated the original post. Thank you for responding c:

Comment: I did a diff between the two code snippets and there is no difference, so it must be something outside of the code that is causing this. Are you sure these image files are on your classpath when you run it? An alternative would be to use `file://` URLs instead of simple resource names.

Comment: I am certain the images are in the right spot. For both programs, they are in the SCR file, which I know isn't the best place for them. I was hoping to talk to my professor about a better way to structure it but with the pandemic, my college is online only now.